# Problem with swiper version 8 and angular version 16

Tags: angular, build, server-side-rendering, swiper.js, angular-ssr

I have upgraded my Angular application to version 16 and I am also using swiper version 8, but when I run the `build:ssr` command, I get errors like this (this problem did not exist in the previous version of my application):

```
./src/app/modules/pages/enterprise-price-list/enterprise-price-list.module.ts:9:18-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper_angular' in 'C :\
Users\asghari\WebProject\Angular\cloud_market_ssr\client\src\app\modules\pages\enterprise-price-list'
```

I removed node_modules and `package-lock.json` and ran `npm i` again but still this error didn't go away, I also tried swiper version 6 - 7 and 9 please help me

To solve this problem, I first deleted node_modules and package-lock-json, and after running the `npm cache clean` command, I ran the `npm i` command, but the problem was not solved, then different versions of swiper, including versions 6-7 and 9 I tried, but still the above problem was not solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the item "swiper_angular": ["node_modules/swiper/angular"] inside "compilerOptions" in the tsconfig.json file.